# How can I execute a Javascript function or not depending on the existance of an element or not?

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
<li id="abc">x</li>
```

How can I use JQuery to check to see if this element exists and if it does then execute the following function?

```
contentControls(ContentButtonAction.Init);
```

Comment: When will the `li` become available? At the beginning in the html code? Or later on from ajax?

Answer (score 2):

```
if ($('#abc').length) {
    contentControls(ContentButtonAction.Init);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the following:

```
if( $('#abc').length ) {
    contentControls(ContentButtonAction.Init);  
}
```